# Prove identical angles for two pairs of unit vectors summed to the same

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to study a geometric relation. Given 4 unit vectors $\vec{a}_i=(\cos x_i,\sin x_i)$ satisfying $$\vec{a}_1+\vec{a}_2=\vec{a}_3+\vec{a}_4,\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$ I want to prove their directions must be identical (up to trivial permutation), i.e., they bear the following simple relation:
either $$x_1=x_3,x_2=x_4$$ or $$x_1=x_4,x_2=x_3.$$ The only exception is that the two vectors in each pair are in opposite directions  $x_1=x_2\pm\pi,x_3=x_4\pm\pi$. We restrict variables in $[0,2\pi)$.

What I have tried is trigonometric sum-to-product relations applied to \eqref{eq1}, but it doesn't seem to work out well. Often one can get relations between, say, $x_1+x_2$ and $x_3+x_4$, but how to get relations between individual variables?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: There is no such "exception".

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos \left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right)= \cos \left(\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{x_3-x_4}{2}\right)
$$
and
$$
\sin\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}\right)= \sin\left(\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x_3-x_4}{2}\right).
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\tan \left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)=\tan \left(\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}\right) \\
\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}=n \pi+\frac{x_3+x_4}{2} \\
\frac{x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4}{2}=n \pi \\
\end{array}
$$
so, $\frac{x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4}2\in\{-\pi, 0, \pi\}.$

I guess you can solve after that.

Note: Before Downvoting note that I had answer his question 2 days ago before he edited it and made it related to vectors.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.